# Missing Jam file in fresh download of boost

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I religiously follow http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/windows.html.

After downloading and unpacking the 1.61 version of boost, I tried to build it from source with the instruction from section 5.1 in this guide.
So

```
bootstrap
.\b2
```

But then I get the error:

```
error: Unable to load Jamfile.
error: Could not find a Jamfile in directory 'libs/config/checks/architecture'.
error: Attempted to find it with pattern '[Bb]uild.jam [Jj]amfile.v2 [Jj]amfile [Jj]amfile. [Jj]amfile.jam'.
error: Please consult the documentation at 'http://www.boost.org'.
```

Exactly the same as [Trac issue #12173 of boost](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12173).
What is going wrong? How can I make bjam find the jam files?

Answer (score 2):

Bit out of date, but I was able to get this working by getting the `config` submodule:

```
git submodule update --init libs/config
```

It seems like the config module is an unlisted prerequisite for some of the other modules.

Answer (score 0):

This error might happen when "bootstrap.jam" is trying to load the modules of the build system from a wrong path.

Make sure that `BOOST_BUILD_PATH` is set to "boost*/tools/build" and that `BOOST_ROOT` is unset.

Example of a WRONG config:

```
libtorrent-rasterbar-1.2.0>set BOOST_BUILD_PATH=..\boost_1_68_0
libtorrent-rasterbar-1.2.0>set BOOST_ROOT=..\boost_1_68_0
libtorrent-rasterbar-1.2.0>b2
Jamroot.jam:1: syntax error at EOF
CXXFLAGS =
LDFLAGS =
OS = NT
building boost from source directory:  ..\boost_1_68_0
boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:262: in find-jamfile from module project
error: Unable to load Jamfile.
error: Could not find a Jamfile in directory '../boost_1_68_0/libs/config/checks/architecture'.
error: Attempted to find it with pattern '[Bb]uild.jam [Jj]amfile.v2 [Jj]amfile [Jj]amfile. [Jj]amfile.jam'.
error: Please consult the documentation at 'http://www.boost.org'.
boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:325: in load-jamfile from module project
boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:64: in load from module project
boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:89: in load-used-projects from module project
boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:75: in load from module project
boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:89: in load-used-projects from module project
boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:75: in load from module project
boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:145: in project.find from module project
boost_1_68_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:618: in load from module build-system
..\boost_1_68_0\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import from module modules
..\boost_1_68_0\tools\build\src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build from module
..\boost_1_68_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

Example of a FIXED config:

```
libtorrent-rasterbar-1.2.0>set BOOST_BUILD_PATH=..\boost_1_68_0\tools\build
libtorrent-rasterbar-1.2.0>set BOOST_ROOT=
libtorrent-rasterbar-1.2.0>b2
Jamroot.jam:1: syntax error at EOF
CXXFLAGS =
LDFLAGS =
OS = NT
warning: No toolsets are configured.
warning: Configuring default toolset "msvc".
warning: If the default is wrong, your build may not work correctly.
warning: Use the "toolset=xxxxx" option to override our guess.
warning: For more configuration options, please consult
warning: http://boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/advanced/configuration.html
...patience...
...found 1058 targets...
...updating 163 targets...
msvc.write-setup-script bin\standalone\msvc\msvc-14.1\msvc-setup.bat
compile-c-c++ bin\msvc-14.1\debug\threading-multi\src\alert.obj
alert.cpp
...
```